# Solve the congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the congruence .

$3x^2+7x+5=0 \pmod{11}$

When I m trying to solve this question 
I.e. 
Multiplying by $4a$

$36x^2+84x+60=0 \pmod{11}$

$(2ax+b)^2=(b^2-4ac)$

AND So we got

$(6x+7)^2=-11 \pmod{11}$

$y^2=-11\pmod{11}$

I don't know how to solve it from here.

Comment: The quadratic formula works fine, so long as the characteristic isn't $2$.   You'll still need to find the square root of the discriminant, if it has one.  Frankly, with such a small modulus, I think it's easier to just try all $11$ values.

Answer (score 1):

$$(6x+7)^2\equiv-11\pmod{11}\equiv0$$

$\iff6x+7\equiv0\iff6x\equiv-7\iff12x\equiv-14$ as $(2,11)=1$

$\iff x\equiv-14\equiv8$

Answer (score 0):

$$3x^2 +7x + 5 \equiv 0 \mod 11$$

- Aiming at square completion, note that multiplying by $7$ is useful:
  $$\Leftrightarrow 21x^3+49x+35 \equiv -x^2 + 5x + 2 \equiv 0 \mod 11 $$ 
  $$\Leftrightarrow x^2 -5x - 2 \equiv 0 \mod 11$$
  $$\stackrel{11-5=6, 11-2=9}{\Longleftrightarrow} x^2 + 6x +9 \equiv (x+3)^2 \equiv 0 \mod 11$$
  It follows:
  $$\boxed{x \equiv -3 \equiv 8 \mod 11}$$